# html encode doesnt encode space

Tags: html, vbscript, encode, space

i have the following function on vbscript:

```vb
Function HTMLEncode(sText) 
    Dim regEx 
    Dim matches 
    Dim match 


    sText = Replace(sText, Chr(34), "&quot;") 
    sText = Replace(sText, Chr(60)  , "&lt;") 
    sText = Replace(sText, Chr(62)  , "&gt;") 
    sText = Replace(sText, Chr(38), "&amp;") 
    sText = Replace(sText, Chr(32), "&nbsp;") 


    Set regEx= New RegExp 

    With regEx 
     .Pattern = "&#(\d+);" 'Match html unicode escapes 
     .Global = True 
    End With 

    Set matches = regEx.Execute(sText) 

    'Iterate over matches 
    For Each match in matches 
        'For each unicode match, replace the whole match, with the ChrW of the digits. 


         sText = Replace(sText, ChrW(match.SubMatches(0)), match.Value) 
    Next 

    HTMLEncode = sText 
End Function
```

However, this doesn't encode space. when i type >, <, ", & they get encoded. but when i type *space* it doesnt get encoded. It does, but its encoded when I enter multiple spaces, for example:

```
"thishas4spaces    word"
```

the first three get encoded except the last space. so it goes like this:

```
"thishas4spaces&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; word"
```

Any idea why? help please. language is vbscript

Comment: Work for me...I get all 4 spaces replaced.  Are you sure the 4th "space" is Chr(32) ?

Comment: Tested using ASP on IIS5 and it seems OK.

Comment: In your example, what is the result of Asc(Mid(sText,18,1)).  the 18th character should be the 4th space.

Comment: yes im sure that the 4th space is the same with the first three. its really weird that the last space wont get encoded

Comment: Your code is not working correct in other ways: when `<`, `>` or `'` gets replaced, it replaces it with `&xxx;`. After that you replace `&` with `&amp;`, so a text like `>_<` gets transformed to `&amp;gt;_&amp;lt;`. Also do not forget to encode `"` and `\`` too.